# Return random result from three SQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an SQL database with three tables inside called...

```
Fruit Name
Fruit Color
Fruit Price
```

I am attempting to return a random result from each of these three tables to give me for example....

```
Apple - Green - $10
```

Currently I am doing this by running the following PHP three times (with a different table for each)

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM fruitname");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['fruitname'];
  }
```

This works fine but I get the feeling I am going about it the wrong way.  Is there a way to do this as one command instead of three?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a *random* row, you can do it this way:

```
select *
from (select * from FruitName order by rand() limit 1) fn cross join
     (select * from FruitColor order by rand() limit 1) fc cross join
     (select * from FruitPrice order by rand() limit 1) fp
```

This returns all the fields in one row.

Note that a *random* row is very different from an *arbitrary* row.  A random row really means that each row has an equal chance of being selected.  An arbitrary row is simply indeterminate.  The first row in a `select` without an `order by` is arbitrary, but definitely not random.